# how to add attributes of the parent taxonomy in the DOM?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, hooks

I am displaying a taxonomy "category" on a node, a view of that node ,and a search facet.

This taxonomy has 2 levels.

How can i add to the rendered HTMLs, i guess using preprocessing hooks, an attribute indicating the taxonomy parent id ?

I would need to apply CSS differently to the taxonomy buttons depending on the parent.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the relevant Taxonomy parent Field to your Views, make it display the term ID. This way you get that information available as a token.

You can hide that field with `Exclude from display` and position it above all the other fields, so you can use it as a token in all of them without worrying about the position.

Then edit the `Style settings` of your "Parent" field that you want to style and enable the `Create a CSS class` option. You can enter the token for your parent TID in there.

Since css classes can't start with numbers make sure to enter a safe start for the class, for example: `myclass-{{ tid }}`

To find the list of tokens you'll have to temporarily enable the option `Rewrite results > Override the output of this field with custom text > Replacement patterns`.

You may need to `Customize field and label wrapper HTML` and/or `Use field template` depending on your particular configuration and output to get the class to show up.

---

Alternatively, you can construct the output of your field on your own with the `Override the output of this field with custom text` and enter what you want the HTML to show:

`<div class="myclass-{{ tid }}">{{ field_output }}</div>`

Comment: the tid does not give info about the hierarchy though

Comment: Tid doesn't show hierarchy directly, you can combine it with the information you get from Parent field, or use the Parent field to nest results.